# Calculate only if cell contains a number

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cells in one row with numbers which I need to subtract and sum like this:

```
=(C2-B2)+(E2-D2)+(G2-F2)+(I2-H2) etc..
```

Always second cell minus previous in two-cell chunks.
And in the end of this row I get result from 30+ calculations.

For now it works without problem, but problem occurs when I introduce non-number data in one of two-cell chunk, which I don't want to be calculated.

Example sheet: [[ link ]](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXcgduebdQNgsyfNu-QfjlB9UbTOyXAs1nIcM3-bgj4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to improve your formula by using built-in functions like

- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)
- [ISNUMBER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296?hl=en) together with [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)